# Will a ThunderBolt 3 (USB-C?) to ThunderBolt 2 cable allow me to use a MacBook Pro as second monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

Yesterday I brought a iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2017) which has two ThunderBolt 3 (USB-C?) ports. I also have a MacBook Pro Late 2013 which has two ThunderBolt 2 (I think) ports. If I buy a ThunderBolt 3 to 2 cable. Would I be able to use the MacBook as a second monitor?

Answer (score 5):

If you mean Target Display Mode, then no - that was a feature only available to a select few iMac models & now defunct.

See Apple KB - [Use your iMac as a display with Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/HT204592) for details.
It was essentially available on iMacs between 2009 & 2014.

Comment: Ok great, thanks for letting me know. Is there any other way to achieve the same goal. I noticed Duet allows me to use a iPad as a second screen. Is anyone aware of anything simular for MacBook Pro's?

Answer (score 1):

As Tetsujin accurately states, you cannot use your MacBook Pro in Target Display Mode nor achieve the same result via a ThunderBolt 3 (USB-C?) to ThunderBolt 2 cable.

However, there are other options you can investigate, but I have no personal experience with them. Two of these options are listed below:

- [Air Display](https://avatron.com)
- [Mirroring360](http://www.mirroring360.com)

In summary, they promise to allow users to share their Mac screens on a variety of devices, including other Macs.

Comment: You could also use VNC to share out a screen on your iMac to the MacBook.